# If $a = b$, then $f(a) = f(b)$ does $f(x)$ need to be a one-to-one function or can $f(x)$ be any type of function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

It shouldn't matter whether or not  $f(x)$ is one-to-one because $f(x)$ is being evaluated at the same argument/input values if $a=b$, then $f(a)=f(b)$, right?

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't matter. It holds for any function.

Comment: A. k. a. "well-definedness."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That’s the *definition* of a function so it must hold for all functions.

Injectivity is the *opposite* of well-definedness.

Answer (score 3):

The assertion "$a=b$" means (essentially) that $a$ and $b$ are different names for the same mathematical object. So any mathematical expression with an $a$ in it is equal to the same expression when you replace $a$ by $b$. Functions have nothing to do with this.

I think you are wondering about the definition of one-to-one. That says that when $f(a) = f(b)$ (so those are two different ways to refer to the same object in the codomain) it must be true that $a=b$ (just one element of the domain, no matter what it's called).